# angularjs error : [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is login.js using angularjs module and the code views index.hbs

```js
(function () {
 'usestrict';
"the initialize angular module"
 angular.module("myAdmin").controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.login = function() {
         $http.post('/admin/',{useremail:$scope.userEmail, userpassword:$scope.userPassword}).
          then(function(response) {
             console.log("posted successfully");
             window.location.href="/admin/home";
         }).catch(function(response) {
             console.error("error in posting");
         })
     } 
 }
)();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <title>Awi Admin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Aplikasi AWI Realtime Lelang Menggunakan Framework ExpressJS dan Realtime Database Firebase">
    <meta name="author" content="Muhammad Abubakar Siddiq - MAS Abbe">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/login.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css">>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myAdmin">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="profile">
          <button class="profile__avatar" id="btn_avatar">
            <img src="/images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
          </button>
        <div class="profile__form">
          <div class="profile__fields">
          <h3 class="text-center">Welcome Admin Lelang</h3>
            <form name="login-form" role="form" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
              <div class="fields">
                <input type="text" class="input" required-pattern=.*\S.* id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="userEmail"/>
                <label class="label" for="fieldUsername">Username</label>
              </div>
              <div class="fields">
                <input type="password" class="input" required-pattern=.*\S.* id="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="userPassword"/>
                <label class="label" for="fieldPassword">Password</label>
              </div>
              <div class="alert alert-warning" id="warning">
                <em class="fa fa-lg fa-warning">&nbsp;</em>Peringatan, username atau password salah
              </div>
              <div class="profile__footer">
                <center>
                  <button class="btn" id="btn-submit" ng-click="login()">LOG IN</button>
                </center>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('btn_avatar').addEventListener('click', 
        function () {
          [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.profile'),
          function(el) {
            el.classList.toggle('profile--open');
          });
        }
      );
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/bootstraps/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script> ==> "this is the angular cdn"
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/login.js"></script> ==> "this is the angular function module init"
  </body>
</html>
```

[issue in github](https://github.com/MASabbe/awilelang/issues/2)

This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception, but i didn't understand why it can't be loaded ?
can anyone enlight me. thanks

Comment: instead of : angular.module("myAdmin").controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http).
Have you tried: angular.module("myAdmin").controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)

Comment: Don't forget to close the bracket at the end: ]

Comment: thanks for fast responds, i'll try immadietly

Comment: Tell me if it works?

Comment: still didn't workout. same issue again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing brackets at the module definition and bracket and parenthesis at the end of the code:

```
(function () {
    'usestrict';
"the initialize angular module"
    angular.module("myAdmin", [])// If your defining your module you have to include dependencies, if there is no dependencies array is empty: []
.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
            $scope.login = function() {
                $http.post('/admin/',{useremail:$scope.userEmail, userpassword:$scope.userPassword}).
                    then(function(response) {
                    console.log("posted successfully");
                    window.location.href="/admin/home";
                }).catch(function(response) {
                    console.error("error in posting");
                })
            }   
        }
    )
    }) // <- theses bracket and parenthesis are missing
    ();
```

I've made that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/vbw48qu1/15/) for you

Comment: done. there is no missing anymore. the main issue still the same. Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2

Comment: the new issue is change to this one Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$injector/nomod?p0=myAdmin. what kind of error is this ?

Comment: it's works !! i am really appriciate for your help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function () {
    'usestrict';
"the initialize angular module"
    angular.module("myAdmin",[]).controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.login = function() {
            $http.post('/admin/',{useremail:$scope.userEmail, userpassword:$scope.userPassword}).
                then(function(response) {
                console.log("posted successfully");
                window.location.href="/admin/home";
            }).catch(function(response) {
                console.error("error in posting");
            })
        }   
    }
)
}) // <- theses bracket and parenthesis are missing
();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
  <head>
    <title>Awi Admin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Aplikasi AWI Realtime Lelang Menggunakan Framework ExpressJS dan Realtime Database Firebase">
    <meta name="author" content="Muhammad Abubakar Siddiq - MAS Abbe">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/login.css'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/font-awesome.min.css">>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myAdmin">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="profile">
          <button class="profile__avatar" id="btn_avatar">
            <img src="/images/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
          </button>
        <div class="profile__form">
          <div class="profile__fields">
          <h3 class="text-center">Welcome Admin Lelang</h3>
            <form name="login-form" role="form" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
              <div class="fields">
                <input type="text" class="input" required-pattern=.*\S.* id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="userEmail"/>
                <label class="label" for="fieldUsername">Username</label>
              </div>
              <div class="fields">
                <input type="password" class="input" required-pattern=.*\S.* id="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="userPassword"/>
                <label class="label" for="fieldPassword">Password</label>
              </div>
              <div class="alert alert-warning" id="warning">
                <em class="fa fa-lg fa-warning">&nbsp;</em>Peringatan, username atau password salah
              </div>
              <div class="profile__footer">
                <center>
                  <button class="btn" id="btn-submit" ng-click="login()">LOG IN</button>
                </center>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('btn_avatar').addEventListener('click', 
        function () {
          [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.profile'),
          function(el) {
            el.classList.toggle('profile--open');
          });
        }
      );
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/bootstraps/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/javascripts/login.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```